# Set transform of view as another view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set a transform of a view as another view. For example I have `UIImageView` and I want to have the same transform in another `UIImageView` like in the first one.

I try to make it by using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`, but I don't know how to get the relative angle of the first `UIImageView`, to make the rotation. Maybe it can be done in different way?

I made a picture to explain the effect which I want to get:

[image: rotation effect]

Best regards,

EDIT: I want to set second one in the same position like the first one. Not in the same place, but with the same angle for example to the border of screen.

Comment: What does 'setting a transform as a view' mean?

Comment: @meaning-matters I want to set second one in the same position like the first one. Not in the same place, but with the same angle for example to the border of screen. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: check the edited answer

Answer (score 2):

It's simply just need to assign the transform of one view to other.
eg.

```
self.imageView1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 45.0/180*M_PI );
self.imageView2.transform = self.imageView1.transform;
```

**imageView2** will same transform as **ImageView1**.

Answer (score 1):

okay, u can get the `transform` of your second image view (20) marked image use that transform to set 4th image view (in your pic) for example,

```
CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageView_2.transform; //say image view rotated transform
self.imageView_4.transform = currentTransform; //last image set its transform to any view that u want to rotate
```

**Edit:2**
i am not get what u want exactly, if u want to place it somewhere, first set the  `frame` and after that apply transform, like

```
self.imageView_3.frame = self.imageView_1.frame; //set the place where u want to place,
CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageView_2.transform;
self.imageView_3.transform = currentTransform;
```

**edit 3**

if u want to rotate back to normal then use like below

```
self.imageView_3.frame = self.imageView_1.frame; //set the place where u want to place,
CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageView_2.transform;
self.imageView_3.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;//currentTransform; //brings back to original 
 //set the position where u want to place
```

Comment: Ok, but how we can set the position of the second like the position of the first one? Transform does not work.

Comment: Can you see the different in position between first and second view? The different means they are located at different angles. It is on the first part of the picture. I want to set the second one like the first one. It is on the second part of the picture, after =>.

Comment: Can we get the difference between position of two views in degrees? It is all what I need.

Comment: "difference between position of two views in degrees" this part is not correct, see position is location of the view, u can't get the position in degree, all u get once it is transformed is a `CGAffineTransform` of the view, by using this Transform u can do whatever you want. and position is in the from of rect 'CGRect' it contains the origin and size and also u can get the `center` of the view related to superview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122396/discussion-between-b-kosmowski-and-shan).

Answer (score 1):

Here using property `transform` and method `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` of `imageView` can do that.
e.g.

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( rotation degree in decimal /180*M_PI);
```

use animation block to animate accordingly.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 180.0/180*M_PI);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
}];
```

**Edit:**

In order to rotate `imageView` same as a another one you can do this by assign `transform` property of rotated `imageView` see code below.

```
self.imageView2.transform = self.imageView1.transform;
```

Comment: Ok, but how we can get the difference between this two views in degree? I know how to do the rotation, but I don't know how to get the rotation degree.

Comment: Ok, so acctually you want the no of degree of already rotated `imageView` so you can pass the same to another one ?

Comment: yes, but I don't know the degree of already rotated, and I need to get the difference between this two views.

Comment: In animation. `self.firstView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth - [SidebarViewController widthForSidebarMode:SidebarModeExpanded], ScreenHeight - k_HEIGHT_TopToolbar);`

Comment: here you creating view frame but i am asking about how you rotating previous `imageView` ..

Comment: I just creating view. I do it when I detect rotation of device. I don't do the rotation of first `imageView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122389/discussion-between-b-kosmowski-and-vaibhav).

Comment: It doesn't work, because when I do this in that way, I have to assign new transform in the same time to the second one. I can't do this. First is set some time ago. Now we have to rotate second, but we don't know the angle. We only know that the second one should be the similar like first one.